# Synchronized photo gallery

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I'm trying to code application using `React Native` and `Expo`. In my app should be a page in which are displayed photos from gallery. My problem is that the page have to be kept updated. To the mobile will be connected external camera and after taking photo, photo will be inserted to phone's photo gallery. Then **I need to recognize some way that in the gallery is new photo. Is there some event or something like that which can trigger my update-function?** Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the user take new pictures through the app, or does the user take pictures on the camera separately? How are you getting the list of pictures from the camera roll now? Can you add some code?

Comment: i don't think you can do that. but you can however use refresh control to refresh new data or you can listen to the app state, when app is reopen try refetch the data